# Changing CSS on Click with JQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick

http://jsfiddle.net/rusticblonde/zg4JG/26/

```
$( "#infodiv" ).click(function() {
   $( "#div2" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {

 });
$("#infodiv").click(function() {
    $("#div2 #div1").css("webkit-filter", "none")
 });
});
```

Hi there,

ive done a fiddle where on click i want to on click display a box with information, and change the colour back to its original. I seem to have got the click box working, however it doesnt change back to its original colour.

I currently have this on hover, but want to not do it with css if i can.

Any ideas if i have missed a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross browser solution:

Make a class say `transition` and remove it on click.

JS:

```
$("#infodiv").click(function () {
    $("#div2").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#div1").toggleClass("transition");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="transition">
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zg4JG/32/)

Comment: Hi Hiral, thankyou very much for these, can it be done so on click again to put the filter back on? (bit like a hover effect)

Comment: argh! it appears to transition really fast (ie. you know you can say how long something takes to change in CSS) can that not be done on the initial transition? Sorry for all the questions :)

Comment: you can always increase the time. change `1s` to `5s` or required time.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$("#div2,#div1").css("webkit-filter", "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed , in your jquery selector.

It should be :

```
$("#div2, #div1")
```